# Adding a tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

i am trying to write a function for a game of domino that gets the scores (5,3s western) 
but i can't seem to get the right syntax but i have an idea

code:

```
    type Domino = (Int,Int)
    type Line   = [Domino]

       score :: Line -> Domino
       score [] = 0
       score  line 
          | (a,b):line =  (a+b) + (score line)
```

The problem am having is since line is a list of tuples i dont know how to represent the head and last of the list and add them

Comment: First of all, you mean `type Line = [Domino]` if you want a `Line` to be a list of `Domino`s. Second, you seem to want guards, not pattern matches in `score`. You can also not add `Domino`s without defining a suitable `(+)`, or more likely what you want, making `Domino` an instance of `Num`. There's also a weird trailing grave accent that will cause you trouble.

Comment: yea sorry my mistake that was meant to be     `type Line = [Domino] `

Comment: You can (and should) edit your post.

Comment: @kazeem It looks like yatima2975 answered your question, but I strongly advise you to formulate your questions more clearly as it will help us in understanding your problem.

Comment: @ThreeFx: I couldn't agree more, the (now deleted) other answer was a valid solution to the code that's posted in the question (i.e. `sum . map (uncurry (+))`) - only the bit about '5,3s' triggered me to do some research :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a miniscule bit of research on domino scoring for fives and threes, I *think* you want to add the first component of the first tuple in the list and the second component of the last tuple in the list (so that `[(3,2),(2,6),(6,1),(1,4)]` gets scored as 3+4=7).

Translating this into Haskell is straightforward:

```
score [] = 0
score dominoes = fst (head dominoes) + snd (last dominoes)
```

The uses of `head` and `last` won't crash on an empty list because we've already matched that case.

It could be that I've totally misunderstood the scoring rules, though, and this doesn't pay attention to doubles.

Comment: Awesome! that really helps simplify things